# C#のプロセス一覧のフルパス取得で管理者権限で実行されているプロセスのフルパスを得る方法

Tags: c#

こんにちは、お世話になります。  
　表題の通り、C#でプロセス一覧を取得して、そのフルパスを取得したいと考えています。  
　そこで、WMIを利用した方法を試してみたのですが、これだと管理者権限で実行されているプロセスのフルパスは取得できないようで困っています。  
ちなみに、ファイル名のみであれば、取得できることを確認しています。  
　とりあえず、試したコードです。

```
System.Management.ManagementClass mc = new System.Management.ManagementClass("Win32_Process");
System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
string list = "";
foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject mo in moc){
string path = ""+mo["ExecutablePath"];
list = list+path+"\n";
mo.Dispose();
}
moc.Dispose();
mc.Dispose();
MessageBox.Show(list);
```

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: どの手段でも構いませんが「管理者権限で実行されているプロセスの一覧は取得できないようで」がはっきりしないと問題そのものは解決しないと思われます。というのも`Win32_Process`で正しく全プロセスを取得できますので、何等か別の問題と取り違えているかと。

Comment: すみません。いくつか勘違いをしていたようです。質問を修正いたしました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

セキュリティ上、保護されているため取得できません。

[`Win32_Process`クラス](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-process)であれば`SeDebugPrivilege`権限が必要と書かれています。この他.NET Frameworkの`Process`クラスにも[`MainModule`プロパティ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.mainmodule?view=netframework-4.7.2)が存在しますがこちらもアクセスエラーが発生します。Windows APIの[`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`関数](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-createtoolhelp32snapshot)はEXEファイル名までは取得できますが、フルパスを含むモジュール一覧を取得する際にはやはりエラーとなります。

Comment: なるほど、やはり実行ファイルを管理者権限で起動するしかないんですかね。